# How to get selected item in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Picker in Xamarin and I want to pass the selected item in Picker to the another page(TablePage). Below this Picker there is a button and whenever it is clicked I want to go to the other page and display the selected value in the pther page.

```
<Picker x:Name="SelectTablePicker" Title="Select table" TextColor="#676FA3" TitleColor="#676FA3" FontSize="Title" ItemsSource="{Binding TablesFromViewModelCollector}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTable}" />
<Button x:Name="SelectTableButton" Text="Select Table" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" Clicked="Selected_Button" />
```

So how I am trying to pass this value is with click event:

```
async void Selected_Button(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var SelectTablePicker = (Picker)sender;
            int selectedIndex = SelectTablePicker.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectedIndex != -1)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new TablePage((string)SelectTablePicker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex]));
            }
            
        }
```

And on the Table Page, I created Label where I want to show the selected item:

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="#" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#FF5959" TextColor="#EEF2FF" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" Padding="0, 0, 0, 10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

And here its controller:

```
public TablePage(string tableName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyLabel.Text = $"{UserName}";
        }
```

But whenever I click the button I am getting an error and I couldnt figure out why.

Comment: please do not tell us "I am getting an error" - tell us **what the specific error is**.

Comment: Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a **button** click event, so the `sender` is a `Button`, not a `Picker`

```
var SelectTablePicker = (Picker)sender;
int selectedIndex = SelectTablePicker.SelectedIndex;
```

instead just do this

```
// SelectTablePicker is the name of your picker
int selectedIndex = SelectTablePicker.SelectedIndex;
```

and even better, you are already binding `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTable}"` so you could just get the value of `SelectedTable` directly from your VM

finally, you want to cast the selected item as a `Table`, not a `string`

```
new TablePage((Table)SelectTablePicker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex])
```

Comment: I got the same error from the first solution. I tried the second solution but didnt work either and I passed it like this: await Navigation.PushAsync(new TablePage(SelectedTable)); but the thing is SelectedTable is not in current context. I am doing it in another model.

Comment: I know `SelectedTable` is not in the current context - that is why I said you get it from the VM.  This is the same thing I told you on your previous question.  Regardless, if you are getting an error or exception you need to use the debugger to track it down and fix it.  Or add try/catch blocks around the suspect code in order to trap the specific exception that is causing the problem.

Comment: this `(string)SelectTablePicker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex])` is almost certainly failing, because you are trying to cast an object to a string

Comment: Thanks, I got the reason. Table is an object,therefore I am not able to get this SelectTablePicker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex]. It comes like ProjectName.Table Do you have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: then cast it to a `Table`.  Or, as I have suggested several times, just get `SelectedTable` from the VM

Comment: To be honest I dont know how to do, I dont work with xamarin usually thats why I am asking questions like this also. I dont know how can I get the value from vm

Comment: See my last edit for how to cast the selected item properly